# What type is Number field?

Tags: spfield

I have a Field, that has `Type="Number"`. What type of variables can I assign to it?
Will the field support `float` or `double`?

```
oListItem["numberField"] = data;
```

What type can `data` be?

[Cross posted from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206902/sharepoint-what-type-is-number-field)

Comment: FYI... We try to avoid cross posting questions between sites because it is difficult for future visitors to find information scattered across multiple sites. In the future, can you try posting on one site first? In this case, you got two completely different answers so I guess I'll leave it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be Double or Decimal or Integer.

Use the ParseAndSetValue method to make sure it converts it to Double (see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldnumber.parseandsetvalue.aspx)

Comment: ... or string. Also keep in mind that ParseAndSetValue is SP2010 specific method.